# calling plots from R into Java application

Tags: java, r, plot, rjava, jri

Is there anybody who is succesfully working with JRI and rJava? I want to put some graphs, plots made in R into my Java application, but without success. Can anybody provide working example. Here is what I found, but its not working.

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
/**
 * @author Nero
 *In this file, I will try to plot a simple example, only to test how it?s possible to plot through java
 *Attention: Nothing will work if you have not included the JRI.jar as library ( through properties)*/

public class TryPlot {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        //start the Rengine (JRI)
        Rengine re = new Rengine(null, false, null);
        
        //in R:  >a<- c(1.2,2.3,4.5) :
        double da[] = {1.2, 2.3, 4.5};
        long xp3 = re.rniPutDoubleArray(da);
        re.rniAssign("a", xp3, 0);
        //look up for a:
        REXP x;
        x = re.eval("a");
        System.out.println(x);
        //THE PROBLEM: The window opens, but nothing happens???
        re.eval(" plot(a)");
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the normal R graphics device works only if you use it in the R GUI, not if started from java or the commandline.
So I used the package "JavaGD" as a graphics device and this works fine.
the Plot is printed in a normal JFrame which can even be extended by subclassing it.